# How to detect the hour changing in ios?

Tags: ios, time

I want to do something like this in my iOS app. Let's say user open the app now. then I want to show a view. during that 1st hour, no matter how manytimes he open the app I need to show the 1st view through out this hour. when start a new hour I want to show the view 2. again after the 3rd hour I need to show that first view.

Like wise
1hr - view 1
2hr - view 2
3hr - view 1
4hr - view 2

How can I monitor this hours changing from my ios app even its not runing in the background

Thank you

Comment: Get hour from `[NSDate date]` and then check for odd/even hours and do your stuff.

Comment: Why do you care about the background as the user won't be viewing anything then?

Comment: because I want to show a google admob from 2 accounts. so we decided to show client add in one our the office add in next our likewise. so if user open the app now he sees the company add . then after he closing it completely and if he opened it again in next our. then it should display the client add

Comment: `NSUserDefault` is best place to store time if you calculated as per your requirement. However you don't need to worry about if application is close because when next time application run, you can get data from `NSUserDefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
     NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [standardDefaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"kTimeInterval"];        
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationNameForBecameActive object:nil userInfo:@{kUserInfoForBecameActive: self.currentTime}];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didBecomeActive:) name:kNotificationNameForBecameActive object:nil];
}

- (void)didBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSDate *previousDate = [standardDefaults objectForKey:@"kTimeInterval"];
    NSTimeInterval secondsPassed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:previousDate];

    if (secondsPassed >= CHECK_SWAP_VIEW) {
        // Change your view here.
    }
}
```

Here you can do like save time when application goes in background or quit. Then whenever application will open check for previous time and then swap your views.

Answer (score 2):

If the app isn't running in the background, you really can't monitor the hour changing. But that doesn't matter since you can't show a view when the app is not running.

When the app is running, just use NSTimer and set it to repeat at the right time to tell your controller that the hour is changing. Let the controller deal with figuring out which view to show.

This is important, because you have to make the decision of which view to show even when the hour isn't changing. For example, when you first open the app.

See [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:)

Comment: +1 This is pretty much the way to do it.  Of course there will also be `NSUserDefaults` involved as well so you can record when "the hour" started, etc.

Comment: yes I used the timer. But it works only when the app is running.

Comment: @user2889249 The point is you only need to know when the app is running.  When the app closes down, destroy the timer.  When the app starts, check if the hour boundary has been passed (you'll need to save this using `NSUserDefaults`).  There is no requirement to do anything in the background.

Comment: then I need to get the current hour from NSDate and store it in user default. when app open in next time. again get the current hour and chk with the userdefault value. Is that the way?